# SSH connects with old hostname

Tags: 12.04, ssh, hostname

I changed my hostname on my Ubuntu (12.04) computer but my CentOS computer still connects to it using the old hostname. How can I make it so that I can type:

```
ssh new_hostname
```

instead of :

```
ssh old_hostname
```

and it will connect to my computer still?

I edited the `/etc/hostname` file and the `/etc/hosts` file and I also restarted my computer and in the terminal it shows my hostname, but ssh still only connects with the old hostname.

Comment: Did you only change the hostname in `/etc/hostname`?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Check `~/.ssh/config`, you can have aliases defined there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you changed the entry in `/etc/hosts` - e.g. for `serverlaptop`:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>   **127.0.1.1   serverlaptop**
>
> ...

Otherwise, you may need to edit the `~/.ssh/config` (perhaps even `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) file on the computer you are trying access the SSH server from to use the new hostname as the short name - e.g.

```
Host serverlaptop
   User wilf
   HostName 192.168.1.48
```

For instance the above entry in `~/.ssh/config` makes `ssh serverlaptop` act as a alias for `ssh wilf@192.168.1.48` - if one does not exist already you can create it (replacing `serverlaptop` with the hostname, and `wilf` with your username) so `ssh HOSTNAME` will work.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.ssh/config` file on my computer. I only have a `known_hosts` file in the `.ssh` folder.

Comment: Do I make tabs next to User and Hostname?

Comment: @TakamaruTaihou, just create the .ssh/config file.

Comment: +1 It worked, but how would I make it so I don't need to do it for other computers that may also connect, or do I have to do it for all computers that I want to connect to my Ubuntu?

Comment: I suppose a method would be to temporarily remove `~/.ssh/config` fix, and then run `ssh -vvv OLD_HOSTNAME` to see how it resolves the hostname. If you want to post any output you can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/648015/edit) it into your question.